# In Javascript, how do I print out a single element in an array every 5 seconds?

Tags: javascript

I have a pre made class [**Msg**] with methods [**.show()** and **.retrieve()**]. The method '.show()' displays a message to the browser as the last list item in an unordered list. The method '.retrieve()' gets a finite amount of messages from a server. It takes a callback method as its only parameter. It will pass an array of strings. Each string in the array contains one message. I have the following code:

**JS:**

```
 Msg.retrieve(function(array) {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           Msg.show(array[i]); 
      }
 });

 // The code outputs all the messages to the screen at once as a bunch of list items.
```

*How do I output one message every five seconds?* I am unsure on how to use the setInterval() method Javascript has.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: (please note that for future reference, instead of editing a post to correct typos, just leave a comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After retrieving, set a timer and shift the array one value at a time:

```
Msg.retrieve(function(array) {
     var timer = setInterval(function() {
         if(array.length) {
             Msg.show(array.shift()); 
         } else {
             // All messages displayed, array is empty
             clearInterval(timer);
         }
     }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: The other answers the stack community gave me helped me get a better understanding of how to use it but your answer works perfectly for my question in need. Thank you @bfavaretto!

Comment: Fixed the code, your edit was rejected before I had a chance to see it. And if you have ny further questions about the code in my answer, feel free to ask, I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    Msg.show(array[i])
    i++
    if (i >= array.length) clearInterval(interval)
}, 5000)
```

`setInterval` takes a function and the amount of time as arguments.

You can also use `clearInterval` to clear an interval.

Comment: How would I use my .retrieve method to get the data? I want to get the data then show the messages one by one. Thanks in advance @doorknob

Comment: @leggooo I suppose you would do `var array; Msg.retrieve(function(a) {array = a})` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
function makeArrayPrinter(arr, delayMillis) {
  var i=0;
  return function printer() {
    if (i < arr.length) {
      console.log(arr[i++]);
      setTimeout(printer, delayMillis);
    }
  }
}

var f = makeArrayPrinter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5000);
f();
```